# Source for a story about stealing and teaching of Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, gezel-stealing, story-identification, chinuch-education

I once heard a reference to a story in the gemara about an amora who is saying a shiur and a certain person in the bais medrash calls the amora a *ganiv* (thief) because he can't follow the shiur so he quotes the pasuk "torah tzivah lanu moshe, morashah kehillas yaakov".

Is there such a story in the Gemara and if so, where?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are referring to the following from [Sanhedrin 91b](http://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.91b.84?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) (translation artscroll)

> אמר רב יהודה אמר רב כל המונע הלכה מפי תלמיד כאילו גוזלו מנחלת אבותיו
>   שנאמר (דברים לג, ד) תורה צוה לנו משה מורשה קהילת יעקב
>
> Rav Yehudah said in the name of Rav: Whoever withholds the teaching of the law from the mouth of a student (i.e., whoever neglects to teach Torah to a student) is as if he robs [the student] of his ancestral heritage. For it is stated *The Torah that Moses commanded us is the heritage of the congration of Jacob*.